# "Load More Posts" with Ajax in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to create ajax pagination on Blog Page..
What I need to do is to display 5 posts initially and then load 5 more when "load more posts" link is clicked.

Below is the javascript I am using:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // ajax pagination
        jQuery('.nextPage a').live('click', function() { 

            // if not using wp_pagination, change this to correct ID
            var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');

            // #main is the ID of the outer div wrapping your posts
            jQuery('.blogPostsWrapper').html('<div><h2>Loading...</h2></div>');

            // #entries is the ID of the inner div wrapping your posts
            jQuery('.blogPostsWrapper').load(link+' .post')
        });
    }); // end ready function
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click the link the old posts get replaced by the new ones, I need to show old posts as well as the new posts...

Here is the Updated jQuery Code which enables the ajax pagination.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.nextPage a').live('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  jQuery('.blogPostsWrapper').html('Loading...');
  jQuery('.blogPostsWrapper').load(link+' .post');
  });
  });
```

The only problem now is the old posts get removed, i need to keep both old and new posts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final code I used and now everything works perfectly...

```
// Ajax Pagination
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.nextPage a').live('click', function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.blogPostsWrapper').append("<div class=\"loader\">&nbsp;</div>");

    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    var $content = '.blogPostsWrapper';
    var $nav_wrap = '.blogPaging';
    var $anchor = '.blogPaging .nextPage a';
    var $next_href = $($anchor).attr('href'); // Get URL for the next set of posts

    $.get(link+'', function(data){
    var $timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var $new_content = $($content, data).wrapInner('').html(); // Grab just the content
    $('.blogPostsWrapper .loader').remove();
    $next_href = $($anchor, data).attr('href'); // Get the new href
    $($nav_wrap).before($new_content); // Append the new content
    $('#rtz-' + $timestamp).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // Animate load
    $('.netxPage a').attr('href', $next_href); // Change the next URL
    $('.blogPostsWrapper .blogPaging:last').remove(); // Remove the original navigation
    });

    });
}); // end ready function
```

Comment: I know it's been a while since you posted this, but I'd like to see the xhtml that goes with this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe try the following code? This is how I got this working on my own site.

replace:

```
jQuery('.blogPostsWrapper').load(link+' .post')
```

with:

```
$.get(link+' .post', function(data){
$('.blogPostsWrapper').append(data);
});
```

Comment: Hello Dirk...

I dont why but the page is realoding when i click the "load more link"...

Comment: Hmm I think that has to do with the .get maybe chance it to:

$.get(''+link+' .post', function(data){

Comment: Hi.

I edited the jQuery code a bit ...
now its loading the page the ajax way but the problem is that it is loading the complete page including header, footer, sidebar, etc..
here is the code..
`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.nextPage a').live('click', function(e)  {
 e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    $.get(link+'', function(data){
  $('.blogPostsWrapper').append(data);
  });
 });
}); // end ready function`

Comment: Could you try to comment I just added? The reason why your code loads the hole page is because now you dont have the filter (.post) which will only sellect the elements with a .post in it.

Comment: Applying your code with .post giving a 404 error :
`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/tory/page/2/%20.post"`

Comment: Hmm weird. Well I don't know exactly how to add the filter with a .get function. The way I did it was just simply creat an other page without any html markup (so no header/footer etc. just the post themself) and append that into my page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add the new posts without using the old ones.

jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) Will replace the data found in your element . Quoted from jQuery API:

> .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned
>   data. This means that most uses of the method can be quite simple:

Comment: append is loading is the with ajax and not removing old posts but it is also bringing out the header, footer, etc again...
here is the new jQuery code:
`// Ajax Pagination
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.nextPage a').live('click', function(e)  {
 e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    $.get(link+'', function(data){
$('.blogPostsWrapper').append(data);
});
 });
}); // end ready function`

Comment: a bit off topic, but you are actually doing the ajax in a wrong way. You should not query another page, but the ajax request should trigger the wordpress loop in a php file and only the required posts are sent back.