# WordPress Ajax post load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been trying (and failing annoyingly) to get an Ajax post loader to work.

This is the jQuery i'm using (its from this previous StackOverflow post: ["Load More Posts" with Ajax in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673524/load-more-posts-with-ajax-in-wordpress) ), but its just not working.. I'm just trying to get an isotope list to ajax load more but everything i'm trying is failing.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.pagination a').click(function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.filtered-posts').append("<div class=\"loader\">&nbsp;</div>");

    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    var $content = '.filtered-posts';
    var $nav_wrap = '.pagination';
    var $anchor = '.pagination a';
    var $next_href = $($anchor).attr('href'); // Get URL for the next set of posts

    $.get(''+link+' .item', function(data){
    var $timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var $new_content = $($content, data).wrapInner('').html(); // Grab just the content
    $('.filtered-posts .loader').remove();
    $next_href = $($anchor, data).attr('href'); // Get the new href
    $($nav_wrap).before($new_content); // Append the new content
    $('#rtz-' + $timestamp).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // Animate load
    $('.pagination a').attr('href', $next_href); // Change the next URL
    $('.pagination:last').remove(); // Remove the original navigation
    });

    });});
```

This is what I'm using for my js but its just not loading anything when I click on the standard previous_posts_link/next_posts_link.

I've put a div container around them to force the .pagination above.. It briefly worked but was only calling the same 9 posts once and then didn't work.

Any help would be great. Or if someone has a different Ajax Pagination guide that they know works ..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* We will edit our javascript snippet with a variable to keep track of the current page, and we add the $ajax call to our ajax function that we will write in the next chapter. */


let currentPage = 1;
jQuery('#load-more').on('click', function() {
  currentPage++; // Do currentPage + 1, because we want to load the next page

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      action: 'weichie_load_more',
      paged: currentPage,
    },
    success: function (res) {
      jQuery('.publication-list').append(res);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
/* The WordPress query to load posts from a (custom) post type */

<?php 
$publications = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'publications',
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'paged' => 1,
]);
?>

<?php if($publications->have_posts()): ?>
  <ul class="publication-list">
    <?php 
      while ($publications->have_posts()): $publications->the_post();
        get_template_part('parts/card', 'publication');
      endwhile;
    ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<div class="btn__wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="btn btn__primary" id="load-more">Load more</a>
</div>


functions.php:

function weichie_load_more() {
  $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'publications',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
  ]);

  $response = '';

  if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
    while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
      $response .= get_template_part('parts/card', 'publication');
    endwhile;
  } else {
    $response = '';
  }

  echo $response;
  exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_weichie_load_more', 'weichie_load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_weichie_load_more', 'weichie_load_more');
```